# Munkres Topology, page 101, question 8:a, b c. Is the Reasooning correct?

Tags: general-topology

This question asks to show if these things are true, and if not give a counterexample.
For (a) it asks to show that $\overline {A\cap B}$ =$\bar A \cap \bar B$. One way inclusion is as follows: take $x\in \overline {A\cap B}$. Then since $\overline {A\cap B}=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B)'$ where $(A\cap B)'$ is the set of limit points. Then so we know $x$ is A and B, or its in $(A\cap B)'$. We now have cases where we have to assume its in one but not in other but i still think the same result will hold.

But $\bar A \cap \bar B$=$(A\cup A')\cap (B\cup B')$. and so x is in A and B, or X is in A' or B'. For the reverse i have a counterexample: $A=(0,1)$, $B=(1,2)$. THen we have that left hand side in our equation is empty, while right hand side is just ${1}$. Now im kind of confused: does the set ${1}$ contain the empty set?

Part (b) asks about arbitrary intersections where sets are indexed by $a$, and is it true that since equality doesnt hold for 2 sets, it wont hold for arbitrary?

Part (c) asks about $\overline {A-B}=\bar A - \bar B$. But we can rewrite this as $\overline {A \cap B^c}=\bar A \cap \bar B^c$ and this is question (a) again: and so we can play the same game, and the counterexample is(im not sure about it actually): Take $A=(0,1)$, $B=R-(1,2)$ where R is the real line.. Then we have the empty set on left hand side, and the set {1} on right hand side.

Comment: Use '\overline' in stead of '\bar'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)$, then $\overline A \cap \overline B = \{1\}$, while $\overline{A \cap B} = \overline \emptyset = \emptyset$. It doesn't matter that $\emptyset \subset \{1\}$, because the question asks if they are equal and $\emptyset \ne \{1\}$. Your counterexample is good. Having this counterexample, that is all you need to provide in the answer to (a). While your analysis of how inclusion holds in the one direction is okay, it is unnecessary.

(b) You are correct. if it doesn't hold for 2, it doesn't hold in general.

(c) Note that

- $B = (-\infty, 1] \cup [2, \infty)$
- $\overline B = B$
- $\overline B^c = B^c = (1, 2)$
- $\overline A \cap \overline B^c = [0,1] \cap (1,2) = \emptyset = \overline {A \cap B^c}$

I'll leave you to figure out the mistake you made.